# Security Issues with RESTful Authentication & Session Management

Tags: rest, microservices, restful-authentication, session-management

I'm trying to implement authentication and session management for a microservice. In order to do the process RESTfully, I understand that I'll need to use some kind of token-based authentication to avoid tracking client session data on the server. The following quote from [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/81756/session-authentication-vs-token-authentication) on the Information Security Stack Exchange nicely sums up my understanding of the implementation:

> In Token-based Authentication no session is persisted server-side (stateless). The initial steps are the same. Credentials are exchanged against a token which is then attached to every subsequent request (It can also be stored in a cookie). However for the purpose of decreasing memory usage, easy scale-ability and total flexibility a string with all the necessary information is issued (the token) which is checked after each request made by the client to the server.

From this, I understand how stateless session maintenance is advantageous for scalability, and flexibility as explained. But it seems to me that this leaves the application exposed to some serious problems:

1. If a hacker somehow intercepts the credential exchange HTTP REST call, they could execute [replay attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack) on the server get all the information they want.
2. In fact, since the session token is stored on the client side, couldn't a hacker just retrieve the requisite information from LocalStorage/SessionStorage by debugging the app? Or by monitoring the incoming and outgoing HTTP calls using dev tools? If they get the required token information (even encrypted token information), they could simply start faking REST calls to the server from another window and get all the data they want!

[image: Replay Attack Wikipedia image]

3. Finally, even if you do give the client a session token, wouldn't the server still have to authenticate *that* token? In effect, the server would have to maintain session tokens to user mappings...but doesn't that defeat the purpose of a stateless REST-based architecture?

Maybe I am seeing these problems because there is a gap in my understanding. If that's the case, I'd like some clarity of the basic concepts. If not, I'd like to know if there are any techniques to address these specific problems.